# Copy contents of input fields to a hidden div

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form one textarea and two input fields. I want to allow the user to be able to click on a "preview" link and get the content of the form that he just entered into a div.

The div is used by a lightbox that will show the content as a preview. Does that make sense? I need some serious help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The only question here is "Does that make sense?".  The answer to that question is "Yes", but that obviously is not what you are looking for.   Please rephrase this so that it actually asks a question about how to do something with code.  I have no idea what you can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery you can do something like the following:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="input-lastname" name="lastname" value=""/>
   <input type="text" id="input-firstname" name="firstname" value=""/>
   <textarea id="input-text' rows="10" cols="10"/>
</form>

<a href="#" id="preview-invoke">Preview</a>

<div id="preview" style="display:none">
   <p id="preview-firstname"></p>
   <p id="preview-lastname"></p>
   <p id="preview-text"></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#preview-invoke').click(function(evt) {
         evt.stopPropagation();
         $('#preview-firstname').html($('#input-firstname').val());
         $('#preview-lastname').html($('#input-lastname').val());
         $('#preview-text').html($('#input-text').val());

         //TODO: invokeLightBox();
         return false;
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" onclick="renderPreview();">preview</a>

<script>
function renderPreview() {
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=document.getElementById('txt-input').value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery version

Working Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yvTNc/4/

**HTML**

```
<input id="inputItem" type="text" size="20" /><br><br>

<a href="#" id="renderPreview">Preview</a><br><br>

<div id="hiddenDiv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hiddenDiv{display:none;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#renderPreview').click(function(){
    $.('#hiddenDivId').html( $('#inputItemId').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="showPreview(); return false;">Show preview</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showPreview() {
        $('#hiddenDiv').html('<p>'+$('#textarea').val()+'</p>').show();
    }
</script>
```